# How nilpotent is the ring of stable homotopy groups of spheres?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Are there any known or conjectured bounds on the exponent $d(r)$ such that $x^{d(r)} = 0$ for all $x \in \pi_r^S(S^0)$?

Comment: At the very least, the proof of Nishida's theorem in II.2.2.9 of Bruner--May--McClure--Steinberger comes with *a* bound, dependent upon the torsion order of the element x, and there are in turn bounds on the amount of torsion that can appear in a particular degree. May says that Nishida's original proof gives better bounds, and maybe more is known besides those initial things, but definitely bounds are known.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $\alpha \in \pi_s(S^0)$ for $s > 0$ be an element of positive degree in the stable stems. Then $\alpha$ has positive-dimensional filtration in the Adams-Novikov spectral sequence: in other words, it is annihilated by complex bordism.

The $E_\infty$-page of the Adams-Novikov spectral sequence for the sphere is known to have a vanishing "curve" of slope tending to zero as $t -s \to \infty $ (this is essentially the Devinatz-Hopkins-Smith nilpotence theorem). The exact behavior of this curve is not known, but there is a conjecture of Hopkins (from [this talk](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.hha/1251832464&page=record)) that it looks like $s \simeq \sqrt{t-s}$. In this case, any element in $\pi_t$ would have nilpotence order $O(t)$, by considering the spectral sequence. This conjecture is (as far as I know) unproven.

It might be worth noting that explicit nilpotence-type results have been proven using power operations (this is the sort of technique that led to Nishida's proof that order $p$ elements are nilpotent), for instance the Toda relation  in [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195521243).

Answer (score 4):

If one uses the Adams-Spectral sequence based on cohmology theories other than $BP$ it is possible to say a little more. In ["A vanishing line in the $BP \langle 1 \rangle$-Adams spectral sequence"](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0040938399000026/1-s2.0-S0040938399000026-main.pdf?_tid=925ef31a-273a-11e4-be46-00000aacb362&acdnat=1408409504_3ee3458e72f9e3556e672c0e21451eea) Jesús González shows that when $p$ is odd the $E_2$-page of the $BP\langle 1 \rangle$-Adams spectral sequence for the sphere spectrum has a vanishing line of slope $(p^2-p-1)^{-1}$. This is used to show that the $E_\infty$-term of the classic ASS has a vanishing line of slope $(2p-1)/[(2p-2)(p^2-p-1)]$. The result you are looking for is then Corollary 4.4:

> > In the $n$-th stable stem, any $p$-local homotopy class not detected by the $J$-spectrum is annihilated by $p^{\text{min}\{4,p\}+ \epsilon_n+S(n)}$, where $q=2p-2$, $S(n)$ is the first integer larger than or equal to $(q+1)n/[q(p^2-p-1)]$ and $\epsilon_n = 0$ unless $n+2$ is divisible by $q$, in which case $\epsilon_n$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $n+2$.